# onClick prop not working when passing a function to another component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component like this

```
<CardAvReport
  buttonProps={buttonProps ? { ...buttonProps , small: true,  onClick: () => console.log("hi")} : null}
  onHandlerExample={this.someotherFunction}
  includeLink
  showChildren
  {...rest}
>
```

This component renders a div, and this div contains a button that is triggered by the onClick.

If clicked I can see the console.log("hi") being triggered.
The problem is that if I call a function like this

```
<CardAvReport
  buttonProps={buttonProps ? { ...buttonProps , small: true,  onClick: () => this.myFunction} : null}
  onHandlerExample={this.someotherFunction}
  includeLink
  showChildren
  {...rest}
>
```

It wont work.

In the CardAvReport, the buttonprops end up in another component

```
<ButtonLink {...buttonProps}>{buttonProps.text}</ButtonLink>
```

This component is defined as

```
import * as React from "react";
import Button from "./Button";

export default props => {
  const { link, onClick, children, ...rest } = props;
  let props2 = { onClick };
  if (link) props2["href"] = link;
  if (onClick) props2.onClick = onClick;
  return (
    <a {...props2}>
      <Button {...rest}>{children}</Button>
    </a>
  );
};
```

I dont understand how to debug this, and why a function wont work in the onClick.

Comment: instead of `onClick: () => this.myFunction` try `onClick: () => myFunction()`

Comment: In the second example, you're not actually calling `myFunction`. It should have parentheses after it to make it a call: `() => this.myFunction()`

Comment: Indeed it worked, had to add  ? to the arg tho, thanks